# VUE 3 not rendering template defined in the custom component, no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, flask, vuejs3

I am using `flask`, `html`, `js` to create a web app.
I am trying to render template defined in component `<add-movie>` inside movies.js, into `add_movies.html`. The `add_movies.html` is extending `base_admin.html` where i have already put vue3 cdn, then I've put a link to `movies.js` in `add_movies.html` below and I am using add-movies tag. It should render template written inside but it is not doing anything, it is logging a message into console which means the movies.js is found by `add_movies.html` but it is not rendering anything on the page.

my folder structure is:
`Website>Static>Components>(all js files) Website>templates>(all html files) Website>(all python files)`

This is my `movies.html`.

```
{% extends 'base_admin.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col" id="movie_card">
        <add-movie></add-movie>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='components/movies.js') }}" defer></script>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my js

```
const movieApp = Vue.createApp({
    delimiters: ["{[", "]}"],
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: (tag) => ['add-movie', 'show-movie'].includes(tag)
    }
  });
  
  movieApp.component('show-movie', {
    props: ['movieTitle', 'movieDirector', 'movieRating', 'movieImage'],
    template:`
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <div class="col">
            <p></p>
            <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;" :class="{ rate: movieRating > 4 }">
              <img :src="movieImage" :alt="movieTitle" class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div id="showName"><strong>{[ movieTitle ]}</strong></div>
                <div id="director">Directed by: {[ movieDirector ]}</div>
                <div id="rating">Rating: {[ movieRating ]}</div>
                <div id="price">Price</div>
                <p></p>
                <a href="/bookings"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Book Tickets</button></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
  });
  
  movieApp.component('add-movie', {
    template:`
      <p></p>
      <form class="form-floating" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"></div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="show_name">Movie name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="show_name" name="show_name" placeholder="Oppenheimer">
            <label for="tags">Tags</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Baner">
            <label for="director">Director</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="director" name="director" placeholder="300">
            <label for="theater_name">Theater Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="theater_name" name="theater_name" placeholder="300">
            <label for="screen_no">Screens</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="screen_no" name="screen_no" placeholder="300">
            <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" placeholder="300">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>`
  });
  
  console.log("from add movies.")
  movieApp.mount('#movie_card');
```

What am i doing wrong?

My `base_admin.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          {% if admin.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="addTheater" href="/theater_management">Add theater</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="summary" href="/summary">Summary</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/admin_logout">Logout</a>
          {% else %} 
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/admin_login">Admin Login</a>
          {% endif %}
          <form class="form-inline search ml-auto" role="search">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
      messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
      'error' %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to render `<add-movie></add-movie>` and `<show-movie></show-movie>` but it is not rendering the template defined in `vue` component.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the compileroptions with `isCustomComponent` blocks execution of the component.
I think it's a definition for tags that are used outside of Vue and should be ignored during execution.

The following explanation is taken from the [documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#autonomous-custom-elements).

> If we want to add a custom element defined outside of Vue (e.g. using the Web Components API), we need to 'instruct' Vue to treat it as a custom element.

Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on Vue.

Comment: Yes I am doing that here const movieApp = Vue.createApp({
    delimiters: ["{[", "]}"],
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: (tag) => ['add-movie', 'show-movie'].includes(tag)
    }
  });

Comment: After commenting out the relevant lines, it should run without errors. I think you are blocking your own component.

Comment: Which lines? 

Comment: `isCustomElement: (tag) => ['add-movie', 'show-movie'].includes(tag)`